# Place order directly by adding product to cart Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3.0

I want to place order programmatically by adding a product from Product view page, without showing cart and checkout.

Please suggest.

Comment: for checkout you have to select shipping method and payment method  how you are selecting these both of product page?

Comment: Check Magento_InstantPurchase.

Comment: you should try this https://www.dckap.com/blog/instant-purchase-feature-magento-2/